# validate text box - comparing two text box values

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, comparison-operators

When I enter a value into the `TxtAdvance` text box, if it is higher than the value in the `TxtAssessedVal` box, the program should show an error message.

```
 private void TxtAdvance_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
 {
       if (float.Parse(TxtAssessedVal.Text) <= float.Parse(TxtAdvance.Text)) 
       {                               
             MessageBox.Show("Advance value shold be less than Assessed value .!", 
                             "Error", 
                              MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                              MessageBoxIcon.Error);

             TxtAdvance.Focus();
             return;
       }
 }
```

But when i entered `90000` for "advance" value and `89600` for "assessed" value it didn't show the error.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: it seems to be fine.. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Ok. And what is happening instead of what you expected? What debugging have you done? What values did you enter into each box in order to test it? You can't just dump some code on us without telling us what the issue is, we can't magically guess what you want to ask about

Comment: It seems you are checking if `TxtAdvance` is equal or smaller than `TxtAssessedVal` not greater

Comment: when i entered 90000 for advance value and 89600 for assessed value it didn't give error message

Comment: I changed the symbol but it didn't work

Comment: "didn't work" is not a problem we can fix. Please give us some proper details about the situation. Did you debug it? Did the comparison code actually run? (We can't see how y ou are triggering the txtAdvance_Validating method). And if it ran, did the textbox values contain what you expected? Did the parsing work? Did you get any exceptions? P.S. I added an answer below with a more detailed description of the likely solution.

Comment: i debug it.but system not generate error.when i entered less value it also save database when i entered higher value it also save database..no validation or no any error

Comment: Have you stepped through the code line by line using the Visual Studio debugger? Or set a breakpoint on your `if` statement (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019 for how to do it)? Did the code stop on your `if` statement or not? If it never even stops there, then simply your validation code is not being executed. As I said, we cannot tell how you are actually binding the validation event to your form. To understand that we'd need to see more of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

`90000` is bigger than `89600` so the expected behaviour of what you've written is that it should not display the error. Your code will be like doing this: `if (89600 >= 90000) { MessageBox.Show //etc....`. In other words it means "If 89600 is greater than or equal to 9000 then show the error". Clearly, 89600 isn't bigger or equal to 9000 so the message is not displayed.

I think you just confused "greater than" with "less than". Try with `<=` instead of `>=`:

```
if (float.Parse(TxtAssessedVal.Text) <= float.Parse(TxtAdvance.Text))
```

Or, if you prefer to make the code read more like your requirement, then swap the textboxes round instead:

```
if (float.Parse(TxtAdvance.Text) >= float.Parse(TxtAssessedVal.Text))
```

P.S. Your requirement also says "if it is higher", but doesn't mention "or equal to". So possibly you need to remove the `=` as well, since in that case if both values are (for example) `90000` then the error will display. So actually maybe the code should be:

```
if (float.Parse(TxtAdvance.Text) > float.Parse(TxtAssessedVal.Text))
```

instead.

---

P.P.S. I recommended that you read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators and ensure you understand clearly the meaning of each operator symbol.

Comment: i changed my code if (float.Parse(TxtAdvance.Text) > float.Parse(TxtAssessedVal.Text))
like this but it not warking